# Set signature for Google user: change code oAuth1.0 with oAuth2.0 (Google Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script

I use a Google Apps Script (found here: http://blog.knoldus.com/2013/01/11/google-apps-script-to-create-signature-block-for-user/) that set a user signature.
Each my user have a signature with same company's logo but with department name & phone number & email different ...
I manage this information. When user change department (7/8 each month) I force signature automatically.
It's possibile adapter old script with new OAuth2.0 ?? (on 20 april Google stop oAuth1.0) 
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: The [tag:signature] tag is reserved for *method* signatures. Please do try and followup on your questions, it seems to me that one of the answers could be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to go to the GitHub website, and use some Apps Scripts files from GitHub.

[GitHub Apps Script OAuth2](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2)

You don't need the README.md or LISCENCE file.  There are only 3 script files.  You could highlight all the text in each script file on GitHub, copy the text, and paste the text into new `.gs` Apps Script files in your Apps Script Project.  Or you could download the zip file, and extract the files, the copy and paste the code.

An alternative to that, is to use a library to reference all the functions in a permanent Apps Script file that Google set up as a library.

The instructions for using the library are on the GitHub site in the README.md file.  It's right there on the page when you go to the link.

The README.md file has some sample code in it, that is designed to work with the library.

So, yes, it's possible to change that code.  You'll end up with more code inside your Apps Script project.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Here is the project re-written for Oauth2. It uses the library that Sandy mentioned.

https://github.com/Spencer-Easton/Domain-Email-Signatures